# How to avoid referencing KV namespace ID in wrangler.toml?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

CloudFlare documentation for wrangler.toml requires this code to add a binding to a KV namespace:

```ini
kv_namespaces = [
  { binding = "ORIGIN_MAP", id = "06779da6940b431db6e566b4846d64db" }
]
```

I would like to avoid referencing the ID directly, since I have a terraform where I'd like to be able to spin up an environment, perhaps in a new account, dynamically. That is, I would like to do something like:

```ini
kv_namespaces = [
  { binding = "ORIGIN_MAP", id = $ORIGIN_MAP_ID }
]
```

Where `$ORIGIN_MAP_ID` is set by logging into the Cloudflare API and calling https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/workers-kv-namespace-list-namespaces to find the namespace with a given title and extract the ID.

Is this supported?

Answer (score 0):

One terrible way to do this is to have a build step that calls the API, rewrites the wrangler.toml file in-place, calls whatever wrangler method was intended (e.g. `wrangler publish`), and then rewrites it back to the original content.